# Python: Importing a submodule or subpackage from the same package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still trying to figure out how to create packages, here is a file structure that demonstrates my problem:

```
/main_package/
    __init__.py
    script1.py
    sub_package/
         __init__.py
         model.py
```

Within the `__init__.py` of the `main_package` let's say I have:

```
import main_package.script1
...
```

And within `script1.py` I have:

```
from sub_package import model
...
```

This doesn't work. When I try to import `main_package` I get an error in the following set of calls: `import main_package.script1` -> `from sub_package import model`

Apparently the `from sub_package import model` within `script1.py` doesn't work.

I tried the following:

`from main_package.sub_package import model`

`from . import sub_package.model`

`from .sub_package import model`

And none of them work. Sorry if I'm making a dumb mistake somewhere, but what would be the problem way to fix my issue?

---

**UPDATE**: Ok some people asked exactly how this happens, so I'll post the actually error message I'm getting and my actual structure and procedure. Sorry, the names are now changed up from the above.

Here is my real package structure for the packages which cause an error:

```
script.py
/MCMC2/
    __init__.py
    main_script.py
    ExoData.py
    Models/
         __init__.py
         model_main.py
```

I run `script.py` in the terminal (i.e `ipython script.py [args]`) and get the following error message (I erased everything that comes after the problem messages and replaced it with `...` to make it clearer).

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/usr/script.py in <module>()
      1 import pymc
----> 2 from MCMC2 import ExoData
      ...

/home/usr/MCMC2/__init__.py in <module>()
      ...
----> 4 import MCMC2.main_script
      ...

/home/usr/MCMC2/main_script.py in <module>()
      1 try: from Models import model_main
----> 2 except: from .Models import model_main
      ...

/home/usr/MCMC2/Models/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 import Models.model_main
      ...

ImportError: No module named 'Models'
```

Models definitely exists by the way.

Comment: What error does `from .sub_package import model` give?

Comment: You haven't mentioned how `script1.py` is executed. Is it imported from some other program or is it run directly as a script?

Comment: With `main_package/__init__.py` doing `from . import script1` and `main_package/script1.py` doing `from .sub_package import model`, it works for me. What version of python do you have? What's your current directory when you run the test? I was in the parent of `main_package` so that the package was found correctly.

Comment: The original version works for me on python, exactly how you wrote it. Where are you importing from and please post the exact error.

Comment: To answer in order:
1. I post the error in an update.
2. scrip1 (in the original part of my post) doesn't really have to be executed, it is simply a submodule of main_package. In fact it doesn't really get executed as the error happens immediately as it begins importing its modules. I guess I don't really need script1.py for what I'm doing, but I want to understand why the above doesn't work.
3. My current directory when I run the test is inside the directory *containing* main_package (made clear in the update). Version 3.5.2.

Perhaps I will try to recreate the error with a simpler case.

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon You first description does not match your second one. You are importing `Models.model_main` in `Models.__init__`, that can't work.

Comment: Ah I see, so how do I do it? Do I need to do `import MCMC2.Models.model_main` or just `import model_main`? In the Models `__init__.py` that is.

Comment: Nevermind I got it, I had to do `from . import model_main`.
Can I ask a follow up question. In the `__init__.py` of my `MCMC2` file, I import things like `import MCMC2.module`. It works there, but not when it's done in a sub-package, like `Models`. How come? I also notice that I can instead write `from . import module` in the top-level package too. Is the latter preferable then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems I was getting confused with the whole package structure. Referring to the structure in the update - in the Models `__init__.py` file I was doing the imports as `import Models.model_main` etc... For it to work I needed `from . import model_main` as well. Thanks for the help by the way.